# get_the_title($postID) OR get_the_title()?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, performance, parameter

I would like to know which could be more performant between these two approaches of getting data of a post

- To use a loop after a `WP_Query($aConditions)` and use functions like `get_the_title()` ... and all the similar functions without passing any parameters
- To call `get_the_title($postID)` with the parameter outside the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're both doing the same thing. If you don't pass a post ID, `get_the_title()` will just use the current post and go about it's business. The performance difference between passing a postID and not passing a postID is, if anything at all, is extremely minor.

[get_the_title() Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)

[get_the_title() Core Function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L0)